# bootstrap dropdown-toggle not working in FF

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, toggle

Any idea why my bootstrap 'dropdown-toggle' doesn't work in FF?

[LINK](http://vuerichb.cc/store/products/board/cruisin/005/)

```
<div class="dropdown pull-right">
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">CART</a>
<div class="dropdown-menu">
STUFF       
</div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: you have a JS error on contact.js at line 8, it migth be blocking the rest of the JS code.. try commenting that line and see what happens

Comment: thanks but didn't change anything

Comment: commented all JS files and still no change. so it's a css issue?

Comment: you can hidden class to "dropdown-menu" normal, when you click the cart using jqury delete the hidden class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your custom.css you have display:block for drop-down menu,thus overriding the bootstrap display:none, so comment it out it and see what happens in FF.

Comment: Thank you. 
You are refering to the 'display: inline-block;' but still no-go :(
btw sorry for the messy custom.css

Comment: No, I am referring to this:.dropdown-menu {
 
  -webkit-transform-origin: top;
  transform-origin: top;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
  animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
  -webkit-transform: scale(1, 0);
  **display: block;**
  transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-out;
   -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0px;
          border-radius: 0px;
    padding:10px;
}